# Should I alter my non utf-8 database (mysql) (default?) to utf-8 on a running Drupal 7 site?

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, drupal-7, collation

I've got running Drupal 7 site on MySQL. Just recognised that I have the Database Encoding (and collation) other than UTF-8 while Drupal 7 docs say it needs UTF-8 (with utf8_general_ci collation). At the same time all my tables are the necessary utf-8 and utf8_general_ci. (I guess drupal setup did it this way).

My questions are:

1. should I leave the whole system as it is or should I just alter my database to required encoding or is it necessary to convert anything after I altered the database to utf-8?
2. Would leaving the whole system as it is cause me any trouble in the future?
3. Is this setting for the database just a default and it doesn't matter at all for me as all my tables are set to the proper utf-8?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may or may not already be in trouble.

When you connect, do you establish the connection as being utf8?  (`SET NAMES utf8`, or whatever Drupal does to achieve that.)

Is the data in your client encoded utf8?  (For English, this does not matter.)

The `CHARACTER SET` of every column that currently exists is already set in stone.  Even if some columns are latin1 and some are utf8, the *client* will see them as whatever `SET NAMES` has established.  The inconsistency does not 'hurt'.  At least not until you try to store Arabic in a latin1 column.

I would not blindly try to change anything without understanding *how* to correctly change it.  Some attempts could make things worse.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. MYSQL is set to character_set_server = latin1character_set_connection = utf8. Do you mean I'm safe? Thanks

Comment: Drupal 7 uses SET NAMES utf8.

Comment: Show us evidence of something that is _not_ utf8.